# Try-clause containing multiple statements

Tags: python, function, variables, try-catch, statements

Let's say I have the following function/method, which calculates a bunch of stuff and then sets a lot a variables/attributes: calc_and_set(obj).

Now what I would like to do is to call the function several times with different objects, and if one or more fails then nothing should be set at all.

I thought I could do it like this:

```
try:
  calc_and_set(obj1)
  calc_and_set(obj2)
  calc_and_set(obj3)
except:
  pass
```

But this obviously doesn't work. If for instance the error happens in the third call to the function, then the first and second call will already have set the variables.

Can anyone think of a "clean" way of doing what I want? The only solutions I can think of are rather ugly workarounds.

Comment: There's no built-in or simple way to do this; you'd have to save the original state to return to, or have some way to reverse the changes and unroll them if any failed.

Comment: @DSM that's more or less the opposite, isn't it? The OP here wants all or nothing, I think.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: yeah, you're right.  I added words in my head to the OP's explanation until it matched.. :-/

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That's pretty much what I thought when I wrote "ugly workarounds"..

Comment: @DSM: Hmm sorry.. Not sure I even understand what the OP of that thread wants?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: yes exactly, all or nothing!

Comment: @Aniss: Jon said it well-- it's the opposite.  There the OP wanted individual control without having to duplicate the try/excepts.  You want to be able to revert the whole thing, which is relatively easy to do if your functions are pure (i.e. side-effect-free) and hard if not.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few options here.

A. Have a "reverse function", which is robust. So if

```
def calc_and_set(obj):
    obj.A = 'a'

def unset(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, 'A'):
        del obj.A
```

and

```
try:
  calc_and_set(obj1)
  calc_and_set(obj2)
except:
  unset(obj1)
  unset(obj2)
```

Notice, that in this case, `unset` doesn't care if `calc_and_set` completed successfully or not.

B. Separate calc_and_set to `try_calc_and_set`, testing if it works, and `set`, which won't throw errors, and would be called only if all `try_calc_and_set` didn't fail.

```
try:
  try_calc_and_set(obj1)
  try_calc_and_set(obj2)
  calc_and_set(obj1)
  calc_and_set(obj2)
except:
  pass
```

C. (my favorite) - have `calc_and_set` return a new variable, and not operate in place. If successful, replace the original reference with the new one. This could easily be done by adding copy as the first statement in `calc_and_set`, and then returning the variable.

```
try:
  obj1_t = calc_and_set(obj1)
  obj2_t = calc_and_set(obj2)
  obj1 = obj1_t
  obj2 = obj2_t
except:
  pass
```

The mirror of that one is of course to save your objects before:

```
obj1_c = deepcopy(obj1)
obj2_c = deepcopy(obj2)
try:
  calc_and_set(obj1)
  calc_and_set(obj2)
except:
  obj1 = obj1_c
  obj2 = obj2_c
```

And as a general comment (if this is just a sample code, forgive me) - don't have excepts without specifying exception type.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try cache the actions you want to take and then do them all in one go if everybody passes:

```
from functools import partial

def do_something (obj, val):
    # magic here

def validate (obj):
    if obj.is_what_you_want(): 
       return partial(do_something, obj, val)
    else: 
       raise ValueError ("unable to process %s" % obj)


instructions = [validate(item) for item in your_list_of_objects]
for each_partial in instructions:
    each_partial()
```

The operations will only get fired if the list compehension collects without any exceptions. You could wrap that for exception safety:

```
try: 
        instructions = [validate(item) for item in your_list_of_objects]
        for each_partial in instructions:
            each_partial()
        print "succeeded"
 except ValueError:
        print "failed"
```

Comment: Cool design, but if you already have an `is_what_you_want` method, wouldn't it be easier to do: `if all(item.is_what_you_want()): for item in your_list): for item in your_list: item.do_something()`?

Comment: True... if is_what_you_want is exception-safe

Answer (score -1):

If there is no "built-in" way of doing this, I think after all the "cleanest" solution is to divide the function in two parts. Something Like this:

```
try:
    res1 = calc(obj1)
    res2 = calc(obj2) 
    res3 = calc(obj3)
except:
    pass
else:
    set(obj1, res1)
    set(obj2, res2)
    set(obj3, res3)
```

Comment: This isn't actually a forum; you've posted your thank-you message in the answer section, and it'll probably get deleted soon, since it isn't an answer. Stack Overflow was specifically designed to discourage messages like this, as the designers felt such messages distract from questions and answers. The closest there is to an approved way of saying "thanks" is the "accept answer" button.

Comment: @user2357112: Sorry. Like I said.. first time. However my post IS an answer.. That is a possible solution to the problem. Anyway thanks for letting me know..

Comment: @Aniss: perhaps, but not if the three temporaries are very large. It's an interesting question in decomposition.

Comment: @smci: Well perhaps it's not the most recommendable solution, just the one I find the easiest and most intuitive. Besides I see no problem in the decomposition if I use a dictionary to save the results. But like I said... still considering the options...

Comment: Don't **ever** say thank you in an answer. Its a possible solution, so post and word it like one. Hopefully my edit accomplished that, feel free to re-edit if you don't like it!